# How does one write "day in and day out"

Tags: idioms, word-usage

I work like a dog day in and day out.
day-in and day-out?
day in, and day out?
, day in and day out?
Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to *[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/day?region=us#m_en_us1238506.049)* you can leave out the *and* and drop the hyphens:

> **day in, day out**
>    continuously or repeatedly over a long period of time.

So maybe:

> Day in, day out, I work like a dog.

Answer (score 1):

I work like a dog, day-in and day-out.

Comment: Can you cite a source?

Answer (score -1):

In standard British English, you just write "day in day out". 
In standard American English, you write "day in, day out" or "day in and they out".
(http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/day-in-day-out)

Comment: Typo there:  "day in and ***they*** out."